# AndEngine and @override errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

I've downloaded AndEngine sources from github and installed new Eclipse with ADT 20.0 (as was said in readme). Now I want to compile AndEngine, but every `@override` in code causes an error. I guess, I shouldn't just remove all `@override`, heh? Any suggestions about this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
After changing compiler level to 1.6 I faced this:[image]. A lot of errors with versionsof android (what to do?) and some stuff with openGL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your JAVA compiler level to `1.6`.

Comment: and perform a clean build afterwards

Comment: It helped, so it's a correct answer. But now I am having some new problems. Updated the post.

Comment: @ПавелОганесян Is your Project Build Target set to Android 4.0.3?

Comment: Nope, it's 2.2. If I will use 4.0.3, will it work on previous versions? Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @ПавелОганесян Yes it will work, you just need to set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>` in your manifest.

Comment: @AlexandruAverescu Thank you, you saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score -2):

If the above mentioned soultion wont work, just try removing "@Override". It worked for me many times.

Comment: Just removing the annotation lowers code quality because the compiler can't tell if your code stops overriding a method. This usually wastes lots of time debugging.